# SQRT formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help me get the correct formula?

I want to calculate the following:

SQRT((Rng2^2) + (Rng4^2))

Here is my code but it is not working

```
Cells(LastRow + 1, LastCol + 4) = "=SQRT((Rng2.Address)^2 & " + " & (Rng4.Address)^2)"
```

Comment: what is "rng2" and "rng4"

Comment: Set Rng2 = IncreAws.Cells(Rng1.Row, Rng1.Column + j)

Comment: Set Rng4 = IncreBws.Cells(Rng3.Row, Rng3.Column + j)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concatenation is in the wrong places:

```
Cells(LastRow + 1, LastCol + 4) = "=SQRT((" & Rng2.Address & ")^2  +  (" & Rng4.Address & ")^2)"
```